# Expand li with new elements in it when user clicks on it

Tags: angular, list, html-lists, expandablelistview

I have a list with delete button on each li. When the user clicks on delete button then that li should expand and show a confirmation message and two buttons only for that li. Currently when i click on any delete button then the confirmation msg is shown for all li's

I have pasted my code in below stackblitz.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oxnnhv

Thanks in Advance

Comment: use index to identify unique item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show variable is shared between all the items. So all the li ui is enabled.
Use use index for the fix, like below

```
<li fxLayout="column" class="field-list-item filters" *ngFor="let eachColumn of fieldViewList;let i = index"
                    (click)="fieldSelect(eachColumn)">
                    <div fxLayout="row">
                    <div class="title-container">
                        <span class="title">{{eachColumn}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="delete-field hide" (click)="showDeleteConfirmation(i)">Del</div>
                    </div>
                    <div fxLayout="column" *ngIf="show === i" id="{{i}}">
                    <span> Please confirm if you want to delete this field view. This operations can not be undone. </span>
                    <div class="confirmation-button-container">
                        <button (click)="cancelConfirmation($event)">Cancel</button>
                        <button (click)="deleteField($event,eachColumn)">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

Component should be modified like this

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  fieldViewList = ['field1','field2','field3','field4','field5'];
   public show: number;

   deleteField(e, column) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('deleteField() : ', e);
    console.log('column : ', column);

  }

  showDeleteConfirmation(index: number) {
    console.log('showDeleteConfirmation');
    this.show = index;
  }

  cancelConfirmation(index: number) {
    console.log('cancelConfirmation');
    this.show = index;
  }

  fieldSelect(column) {
    console.log('FieldSelect() : ', column);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ggsqgq). Use a `show` variable for every `item` like this:

```
fieldViewList = [
  {
      title: 'field1',
      show: false
  },
  {
      title: 'field2',
      show: false
  },
  {
      title: 'field3',
      show: false
  },
  {
      title: 'field4',
      show: false
  },
  {
      title: 'field5',
      show: false
  }
];
```

This allows you to toggle every item separatly.

Do not forget to modify view like this: `*ngIf="eachColumn.show"` and `{{eachColumn.title}}` and access the columns using `column.show = true;` in component.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the below code and it should work. Now instead of setting show, you can assign which item to show.

```
  showDeleteConfirmation(e, eachColumn) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('showDeleteConfirmation');
    this.show = eachColumn;
  }
 <div fxLayout="column" *ngIf="show === eachColumn">
```